# W7 installation on Asus M4A88T-V USB3 motherboard (Solved)

Tags: windows-7, installation

Trying to install W7 64 bit on a Asus M4A88T-V USB3 motherboard.

Sata config in bios is set to IDE, which is default when I load defaults in bios, only other option is AHCI which I tried also.

Problem, setup does not see any hard drive, Sata spinning drive installed and is good, other boot disc utilities like active@ find it. Drive is connected to Sata 1 or 2

I have tried every chipset driver i can find, but when I load drivers from usb windows claims either no driver found or no signed drivers.

Tried drivers from [Asus](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A88TV_EVOUSB3/HelpDesk_Download/) and [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-8-series-chipsets/880g)

880G chipset from my research but I could be wrong?

How to get drivers installed during W7 setup? What am I missing?

Note: Windows 10 installer does not see the drive either.

I tried the [Asus EZ Installer](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/EZ%20Installer/HelpDesk_Download/), but this did not work either. Same problem.

[EZ Installer FAQ](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1038870)

Asus chat support wants a serial number which I don't have (on the box which is gone). Looked on the board and in the Bios. This company is hard to get along with.

**Tried a different power connector to the hard drive, seems to have fixed the issue, consider this question closed.**

Bang head here>>>X

Comment: Windows 7 by default does not support being installed from a USB 3 device.  You will have to modify your Windows 7 ISO to include the appropriate driver.  It is not clear from your question, if you have added the required USB drivers to your ISO, I assume your getting stuck on a driver selection prompt.  You should of course be using AHCI not IDE in a case like this.  Verify you are not booting the environment into a Legacy Mode. Doing so will mimic the problems you describe (not showing storage devices)

Comment: Its corked into a usb 2.0 port.  I tried ahci and ide.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ramhound

Comment: Insufficient power can also mimic the symptoms you describe :-)

Comment: You are correct, never thought of that until I suffered first. :-(  I think its quantum physics that any computer will boot, only a billion things that can go wrong! I appreciate your comment as it got me thinking again. :-)